# Stuck on Magento Configuration

Tags: database, magento, configuration

I'm a newbie users, 
I have a problem when I installing Magento stack, 
I use XAMPP, 
I've created Database in localhost/PHPMyAdmin,
I fill all the form, like Host, Database Name, Username, User Password 
when I click Continue, it brings me to the same page.

Is there any solutions ? please help me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

username should be root and leave the password blank, if it still not passing to next page change the base url to http://127.0.0.1/yourdirectory

Comment: I have tried but not able to get success please suggest me another way thanks

Comment: is there any error messages ? is your database name correct ?

Comment: yes my database name and mysql user name is correct I have verified.
and no error message is showing